# Python / PIL - Raw RGB565 data to PNG?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have raw RGB565 data as a bytes-like object and I want to save it as a PNG.
Although it is possible with libraries such as PyQt5, *as you can here:*

```
QtGui.QImage(data, width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB16)
```

I would like to use only PIL, but I cannot find a way to do this with only PIL.
More generally, a method that does not involve Qt would be fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It so happens that the `pypng` repository has a tool to convert from Kobo's 15-bit to PNG.
It's here: https://github.com/drj11/pypng/blob/master/code/kobo565topng

One word of warning however, it outputs an 8-bit RGB PNG.
You don't save any space by saving it as an R5G6B5 PNG, so that might not matter much.